Opacity in Beamer with Items and Colored Text
As a follow up to a previous question, I was wondering how, starting from the setting
\documentclass{beamer}
 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

First of all,
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

We have that
%
\begin{equation*}
2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation*}
%
as it is well-known.

\bigskip

Also, we have that
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

it is possible to have three slides, where

in the first there is the frame described above,
in the second there is only 2+2=4 not opaque, with the rest opaque,
in the third 2+2=4 is colored in red.

I tried the following, but I always found very difficult to handle the opacity of the bullets.
\documentclass{beamer}
     
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1>

First of all,
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

We have that
%
\begin{equation*}
2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation*}
%
as it is well-known.

\bigskip

Also, we have that
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

%%%
\onslide<2>

\color{lightgray}
First of all,
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

We have that
%
\begin{equation*}
\textcolor{black}{2 + 2 = 4}
\end{equation*}
%
\color{lightgray}
as it is well-known.

\bigskip

Also, we have that
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

%%%
\onslide<3>

\color{lightgray}
First of all,
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

We have that
%
\begin{equation*}
\textcolor{red}{2 + 2 = 4}
\end{equation*}
%
\color{lightgray}
as it is well-known.

\bigskip

Also, we have that
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\end{overprint}

\end{frame}

Thanks a lot in advance for any feedback.

\documentclass{beamer}
 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{uncoverenv}<1>
First of all,
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

We have that
%
\end{uncoverenv}%
\begin{actionenv}<uncover@1-3|alert@3>
\begin{equation*}
2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation*}
\end{actionenv}

\begin{uncoverenv}<1>
as it is well-known.

\bigskip

Also, we have that
%
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}
\end{uncoverenv}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thanks for the answer: this looks great! Only, I am not sure I see how we get the red text: I just cannot find a command in your code that works on that, so that if we want to change that color to be green, we can act accordingly.

@Kolmin The alert@3 action will change the text colour to red on the 3rd overlay. If you want green, you can either redefine the alerted text beamer colour or define a new action.

Yep, I suspected that. Thus, if I would like to get on a third slide one $2$ in red and another $2$ in green I have to define a new action. May I ask you the relevant part of the beamer manual where I can see how to deal with this?

If you only want to change some characters, you could also use \textcolor<3>{blue}{$2$}

Wonderful. Thanks a lot!
